# After preflight (cors) request server change origin to * and chrome not display request (but i look response body). How to solve a problem?

Tags: reactjs, express, cors, apollo-server, reactql

After preflight (cors) request server change origin to * and chrome not display request (but i look response body).

[Request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPg75.png)

Chrome's error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:6529/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

I use express, cors, graphql, apollo on backend and react on frontend.

Cors configuration (backend):

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
    maxAge: 86400,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'].join(','),
}));
```

Headers configuration (frontend)

```
const credentials = "include";

let client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> | null = null;

export function createClient(cookie: any, ctx: any, store: any): ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> {
  storage.setItem("ctx", ctx);
  client = new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    link: ApolloLink.from([
          onError(({graphQLErrors, networkError}) => {
            if (graphQLErrors) {
              if (!SERVER) {
                const redirectUrl = getRedirect(graphQLErrors);
                if (redirectUrl) {
                  location.assign(redirectUrl);
                }
              }
              graphQLErrors.map(({message, locations, path}) => {
                console.log(
                    `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
                );

              });
            }
            if (networkError) {
              console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);

            }
          }),
          new ReduxLink(store),
          new BatchHttpLink({
            credentials,
            uri: GRAPHQL,
            headers: cookie,
            fetchOptions: {
              withCredentials: true,
              credentials,
            },
          }),
        ],
    ),
    ssrMode: SERVER,
    connectToDevTools: true,
  });
  return client;
}
```

How to solve a problem?

Comment: but according to `app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000'` backend should not return `*`. Are you using any browser plugin aimed on replacing HTTP headers?

Comment: @skyboyer, no, but even if chrome has such, then there is definitely no firefox (and there is the same situation)

Comment: then check in Developer Tools -> Network what is returned. I mean it may be something like "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, http://localhost:3000" and this may give you insight what may modify header

Comment: @skyboyer, i add screenshots, where can see all the headers - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPg75.png

Comment: so server answers correctly on OPTIONS but for some reason responses with `*` on POST. try this way

Answer (score -1):

I just went through the problem myself and it was a nightmare. The reason it is not working is that the CORS header must have a `.` in it. `http://localhost:3000` doesn't meet that qualification.

I solved this issue by going into my host's file (on a Mac: `/etc/hosts`) and redirecting a dummy domain such as `api.myapp.local` to 127.0.0.1 (localhost). Then I redirected my frontend to `app.myapp.local`. So now when the CORS request is made it is from `http://app.myapp.local:3000` to `http://api.myapp.local:3001` and it meets that requirement. You can call the domain whatever you would like.